# Custom Application Insights module not firing

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I have a custom module:

```
public class MyTelemetryModule : ITelemetryModule
{
    public MyTelemetryModule()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyTelemetryModule: " + nameof(MyTelemetryModule));
    }

    public void Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyTelemetryModule: " + nameof(Initialize));
    }

    public void OnBeginRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyTelemetryModule: " + nameof(OnBeginRequest));
    }

    public void OnEndRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyTelemetryModule: " + nameof(OnEndRequest));
    }
}
```

It's registered in `applicationinsights.config` but only the constructor and the `Initialise()` methods are ever called.